# Import failed in CRM 2015 - Unmanaged

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to import an unmanaged solution from dev environment to the production environment. But, without any other status or log file, even before the Importing begins, I get this error as below:

"An error has occurred. {0}{1}"

This happens even before the importing starts (right after I select the .zip file). Also, there's no log file where I can download and look into the issue.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for on premise?

Check the CRM folder location: *SystemDrive:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CustomizationImport*

There is not enough space

Comment: No, this is for CRM Online.

Comment: I further was able to narrow down that my some of my Web Resources are giving problems. When I don't include any, I can move nicely, so I need to check my Web Resources for the same, both, managed and unmanaged.

Comment: I found a solution to this.
This was because the name of a Web Resource was duplicated in the solution somehow in which I was trying to import.
removed one of the duplicates, so I was able to import it correctly.